# Web servers buffer

Tags: c++, c, buffer

I'm studying networking in C/C++ so sockets.
For example I'm now using firefox and I can load both 10KB pages and 30MB pages. So I assume that all the data I get from web server is written into some buffer.. but is that buffer fixed size or maybe based on Content-size?

Comment: If the `Content-size` is known in advance, the browser probably allocates a buffer of that size right away. If the size is not sent, it most likely reads chunks of data (say 256 bytes) and reallocate every chunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is actually flowing from buffer to buffer to buffer and eventually winding up in memory. The server reads from disk through a disk buffer and writes into a TCP network buffer which its kernel empties into a network interface buffer. The data travels over the network from buffer to buffer as it crosses various network links. Eventually, it winds up in the TCP connection buffer of your operating system which your browser keeps emptying into a buffer in main memory. These buffers are all various different sizes, some fixed, some variable.

Answer (score 0):

In a server or browser, one implementation is a array/vector of pool queues containing *buffers of [power-of-2] increasing buffer sizes, starting with an 'average page size' - an array of bins.  Load up the bins at startup with some reasonable number of buffers.  If the network rx fills a buffer, get one from the next bin up, link it to the first one and start filling that, and so on.  If the first buffer has a Content-size, so much the better - you can pick a buffer, (or vector of buffers to speed up rendering to improve user-experience) of the appropriate size.  If you're clever about it, you can start rendering the first buffer before the second one is completely full, and so on.

Depending on loading, you can adjust the bin contents dynamically to adjust to the current demand.  Obviously, all the bins, queues etc. will be thread-safe, (I use blocking producer-consumer queues).